# BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this update controller in Laravel-5.8

```
  $leavetype = HrLeaveType::findOrFail($id);
  $leavetype->leave_type_name             = $request->leave_type_name;
  $leavetype->leave_type_code             = $request->leave_type_code;
  $leavetype->description                 = $request->description;
  $leavetype->company_id                  = Auth::user()->company_id;
  $leavetype->created_by                  = Auth::user()->id;
  $leavetype->created_at                  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $leavetype->is_active                   = 1; 
  
  $leavetype->save();                         

  $employeetypes = HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->get();

  foreach ($employeetypes as $key => $employeetypes){
    $leavetypedetail = HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->get();

    $insert_array = [
        'no_of_days'                        => $request->no_of_days[$key],
        'employee_type_id'                  => $request->employee_type_id[$key],     //$request->employee_type_id[$key],    
        'weekend_inclusive'                 => isset($request["weekend_inclusive$key"]) ? 1: 0,
        'leave_type_id'                     => $leavetype->id,
    ];                

    $leavetypedetail->update($insert_array);
  }
```

view

```
  @foreach($leavetypedetails as $key => $leavetypedetail)
     <tr>
       <td width="5%">
            {{$key+1}}
       </td>                             
       <td width="30%">  
            <span>{{$leavetypedetail->employeetype->employee_type_name}}</span> 
       </td>
       <td style="display: none">  
          <input type="hidden" name="employee_type_id[]" value="{{$leavetypedetail->employeetype->employee_type_name}}" class="form-control employee_type_id">
       </td>                                
       <td width="20%"><input type="number" name="no_of_days[]" value="{{$leavetypedetail->no_of_days}}" placeholder="Enter leave days here" class="form-control no_of_days" max="120">
       </td>                                                               
       <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="weekend_inclusive{{$key}}"  class="form-control" data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="NO" data-on-text="YES" value="1" {{  ($leavetypedetail->weekend_inclusive == 1 ? ' checked' : '') }}></td>                         
     </tr>
  @endforeach
```

When I submitted the form, I got this error:

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist
> app\Http\Controllers\Leave\LeaveTypesController.php(268): Illuminate\Support\Collection->__call('update', Array)

and it points here:

> $leavetypedetail->update($insert_array);

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($employeetypes as $key => $employeetypes){
  $leavetypedetail = HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->get();

  $insert_array = [
      'no_of_days'                        => $request->no_of_days[$key],
      'employee_type_id'                  => $request->employee_type_id[$key],     //$request->employee_type_id[$key],    
      'weekend_inclusive'                 => isset($request["weekend_inclusive$key"]) ? 1: 0,
      'leave_type_id'                     => $leavetype->id,
  ];                

  $leavetypedetail->update($insert_array);
}
```

Query method: `->get()` returns Collection and on last line of foreach statement you are calling `update` method on it.
You have to call update method on `Model` or on `Query` objects.

Also you have one unnecessary foreach statement. You can update multiple rows without using foreach loop

In this case you can use following code:

```
  ... // other code here
  $leavetype->save();                         
  // after this line delete foreach and place only this code:

  $insert_array = [
    'no_of_days'                        => $request->no_of_days[$key],
    'employee_type_id'                  => $request->employee_type_id[$key],     //$request->employee_type_id[$key],    
    'weekend_inclusive'                 => isset($request["weekend_inclusive$key"]) ? 1: 0,
    'leave_type_id'                     => $leavetype->id,
  ];

  $employeetypes = HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->update($insert_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $leavetypedetail = HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->get();
```

since you are using 'get()'  ....  $leavetypedetail is now a collection, not an instance of query builder,
and the collection does not have an update method

you can replace:

```
  $leavetypedetail->update($insert_array);
```

with:

```
 HrLeaveTypeDetail::where('leave_type_id', $id)->->update($insert_array);
```